# How to populate a collection that contains an object as an element and parameter is passed for an element of the object?

Tags: backbone.js

My webservice returns some thing like : (a list of objects, say ageList)

```
  id : 1,
  age : 20,
  reference : {
     id : 1,
     reference_type : CURRENT,
  },
```

where reference is an object. I have models and collections for both reference and ageList

How do I define a method , preferably in the ageList Collection so that I can get all those objects in which the **reference.id** is "1", which I want to pass as parameter?
What other approach can I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
ageListCollection.filter(
  function(ageListModel) {
    ageListModel.get('reference').get('id') === 1
  }
);
```

after having created your collection (`AgeList`) and the `Reference` model for each of its models, from data returned by the webservice.

E.g : [jsfiddle.net/xiris/yftUN/9](http://jsfiddle.net/xiris/yftUN/9)

Have a look at [Backbone doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) and [Underscore doc](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter).

Comment: Calling fetch from the collection throws an error :
GET http://localhost:8080/js/model.js 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

You can start by reading [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/) which will do that for you if you define your model with some relations